# How read big csv file and read each column separatly?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dataframe, readfile

I have a big CSV file that I read as dataframe.
But I can not figure out how can I read separately by every column.

I have tried to use `sep = '\'` but it gives me an error.

I read my file with this code:

```
filename = "D:\\DLR DATA\\status maritime\\nperf-data_2019-01-01_2019-09-10_bC5HIhAfJWqdQckz.csv"


#Dataframes implement the Pandas API
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv(filename)
df1 = df.head()
```

When I print my dataframe head I have this result:

[image]

In variable explorer my dataframe consist only 1 column with all data inside:

[image]

I try to set `sep = ''` with space and coma. But it didn't work.
How can I read all data with appropriate different columns?
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a tab separated file use `\t`

```
df = dd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')
```